# Nginx rewrite rules with try_files

Tags: .htaccess, nginx

I need help to converting this .htaccess to Nginx. Here is the .htaccess code:

```
RewriteRule wp-content/thesis/skins/(.*)/css.css wp-admin/admin-post.php?action=thesis_do_css
```

I already convert those rules to online nginx converter. So far I get this code:

```
 rewrite /wp-content/thesis/skins/(.*)/css.css /wp-admin/admin-post.php?action=thesis_do_css;
```

I put those code above under try_files rules. Here is the complete code:

```
 location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri$is_args&$args;
  rewrite /wp-content/thesis/skins/(.*)/css.css /wp-admin/admin-post.php?action=thesis_do_css;
  }
```

So, it doesn't work. Please help me understanding about nginx rules. Thanks.

Beny

Comment: try adding the word `last` before the `;`, which should be equivalent to `[L]` in htaccess

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. Basically, I want to rewrite this url: http://mydomain.com/wp-content/thesis/skins/classic-r/css.css

to

http://mydomain.com/wp-admin/admin-post.php?action=thesis_do_css

Answer (score 1):

`try_files` is final. You cannot put anything after it and expect it to be evaluated. Think of try files as an if-then-else statement, where the last part is always the else. Since there are probably a lot more rules involved, you are best off consulting the [WordPress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx).

Answer (score 0):

If you need just to rewrite that one css.css file to wp-admin/admin-post.php?action=thesis_do_css then try this:

```
    if ($request_filename ~ wp-content/thesis/skins/classic-r/css.css ) {
            rewrite ^ http://mydomain.com/wp-admin/admin-post.php?action=thesis_do_css? permanent;
    }
```

That should be within your `server{` block. Make sure to change mydomain.com to your actual domain, of course.

I hope that helps.